# Why is the sentence, "毎日、AからＢに通います。" incorrect?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

In the exam, my sentence was corrected from,

> 毎日、A から B に通います。

to,

> 毎日、A から B に通っています。

...and no explanation was made. I am still very confused.

Comment: I think it depends on what you want to say in the original language (or situation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Habitual actions require the 〜ている pattern.  This is a habitual action since you specify 毎日.

Comment: Can't both forms express that, though? 
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11925/habitual-aspect