# Why doesn't 「毎日学校に行ってきます」work?

Tags: usage, expressions, collocations

This question stemmed from [comments](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/84012/can-i-use-%E3%81%A6-connecting-form-with-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B/84015?noredirect=1#comment136356_84015) under another Q&A where @Chocolate points out that「毎日学校に行ってきます」doesn't work but 「今から学校に行ってきます」is fine. But I am still not quite sure why it doesn't work? When people leave home for school or work every day there is a routine 「行ってらっしゃい」「行ってきます」 exchange. I'd like to know why we can say 「毎日電車で学校に行く」but not「毎日電車で学校に行ってくる」.

Why don't 「毎日」and「行ってくる」like each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Saying 毎日学校に行って**くる** implies the "mental point of view" of this sentence is fixated to the speaker's home, but I think that's weird. A sentence like "I go to school every day" is usually used outside one's home, and returning home is not really part of the purpose of this habitual action. Compare this with ママは毎日スーパーでリンゴを買ってくる, which is natural. Here, fixating the point of view to the speaker's home is natural, and bringing apples home is part of the purpose of this habitual action.

Instead of くる, you may need ている to describe a habitual action like this. See: [Habitual aspect](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11925/5010)