# Can "何？何やってるの？" also mean "What does he do?"

Tags: comedy

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vJRmrL-m3k&t=0m37s

(ねんねん):

じゃ勝俣くんもだめだな 勝俣くんもアウト 何？何やってるの？ 哀：自営業

*Then Katsumata is no good either, he's no good, what, what do you do? Sho: I'm self-employed.*

or

*Then Katsumata is no good either, he's no good, what, what does he do? Sho: He's self-employed.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, depending on the context, 何やってるの can be a question about someone's occupation. Of course the same sentence can also mean "What are you doing (now)?" This is natural because the -teiru form can describe one's habitual action. See: [Habitual aspect](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11925/5010)

The answer can be in the -teiru form, too, e.g., 保育士をしています, お米を作っています, 歌手やってます, 電車を運転している人です.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I also thought maybe 遠藤 said "勝俣くん" after he asked "何やってるの？". It's very faint but if you listen closely, he definitely said something.