# Understanding もらっている in this sentence

Tags: grammar, aspect, giving-and-receiving

> 珠世さんに手当をして**もらっている**が、怪我は完治してない

Why is the progressive used here?

Comment: Can you provide the context?

Comment: person 1 got hurt from battle, and then person 2 healed him, few chapters after, person 1 said this. basically something that despite being healed, it still didnt healed completely (that injury from the battle) Sorry if it doesnt make too much sense.

Comment: You have no difficulty understanding the latter half 「怪我は完治して(い)ない」, which also uses the 「～ている」 form?

Comment: yep, because im sure that here it means something like "まだ怪我は完治してない" which is something like "the injury still hasnt completely healed (but it probably will in future) like as if some transformation from "not being healed" - 完治してない to the state of "being healed" 完治してる. but the もらっている im really not sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Tamayo is not present in this scene, this ている is not progressive but perfective. It describes the continuation of a resultant state. See: [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010)

> 珠世さんに手当をしてもらっているが、怪我は完治してない。
> Tamayo has treated me, but my injury has not been fully healed.
> <sup>(Or more literally...) I have received from Tamayo a favor of treating me, but my injury has not been fully healed.</sup>

As Chocolate suggested, if you can understand 完治してない, this もらっている has exactly the same type of ている.

In this case, a simple past form (-た) and a present perfect form (-ている) both make sense. It's also natural to say 珠世さんに手当をしてもらったが ("Tamayo treated me, but...").

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned another possible interpretation. If she currently treats him on a regular basis (e.g., every week), this ている can be interpreted as "habitual aspect". See this: [Habitual aspect](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11925/5010)

Therefore, if there is no context, there are three possible interpretations of 珠世さんに手当をしてもらっている:

- **Progressive**: Tamayo is treating me (right now)
- **Habitual**: Tamayo treats me (on a regular basis)
- **Perfective**: Tamayo has treated me (and its result is present)

Comment: So the もらっている is used basically because she treated him, and the treatment goes on and on? by that i mean, he said 完治してない, which means "still hasnt healed", so i suppose, she gave him some treatment, and that treatment is relevant up until the point of him saying this. that why the もらっている is used?

Comment: @bulgur69 Yes, if he believes her treatment was quite effective (if not perfect), it means the results of her past action (treatment) is right there on his body now, so he is more likely to use the teiru-form for resultant state. But her treatment itself may be a short action that happened only once long time ago.

Answer (score -3):

It's progressive in the sense **you have been receiv-ing** treatment.

Just like in English language, it's present perfect. The action is still on-going if you will.
In your example you do not expect to have your injury heal anytime soon and the healing of Mr. Tamayo is one event in the continuation of that story.

Now if you are new to Japanese language you have to prepare yourself to see the extensive use of present of any form to express either something that happened in the past or an expected thing happen-ing in the future.